# Can you help me understand this proof of $P \vdash Q \rightarrow P \land Q$?

Tags: logic, proof-explanation

In an introductory book to Discrete Mathematics, there is an exercise where the reader needs to prove the theorem $P \vdash Q \rightarrow P \land Q$.

The book gives the following solution to the exercise:
$\frac{Q\;\;\frac{P\;\;\;Q}{P \; \land \; Q}\{\land I\}}{Q \; \rightarrow \; P \; \land \; Q}\{\rightarrow I\}$

In the provided solution, $Q$ is assumed and discharged twice: once when using $\land$ introduction and once when using $\rightarrow$ introduction.

I guess I understand why $Q$ needs to be assumed in the $\land$ introduction. We have $P$ from the hypothesis and we need to assume $Q$ to use and-introduction thus, we have a proof of $P\;\rightarrow\;Q$ that assumes $Q$, i.e., $Q\;\vdash\;P\;\land\;Q$. But why does it need to be assumed a second time? Also, why does it need to be discharged?

Comment: Which book are you referring to?

Comment: Discrete Mathematics using a Computer, by Cordelia Hall and John O'Donnell, a very pleasant introductory book which, up until this exercise, I managed to understand without help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In the provided solution, $Q$ is assumed and discharged twice: once when using $\land$ introduction and once when using $\rightarrow$ introduction.

Conjunction Introduction does **not** discharge any assumptions. When two propositions are true we may make the inference that their conjunction is true, within the same context.

$$\dfrac{A\quad B}{A\wedge B}{{\wedge}\mathsf I}$$

Conditional Introduction discharges assumed antecedents.  When the consequent is derived *under that assumption*, we discharge that assumption to deduce that the conditional statement holds outside the context of that assumption.

$$\dfrac{A\quad [B]^1}{B\to A}{{\to}\mathsf I^1}$$

**Further we may discharge as many ocurrences of that assumption as the proof requires.**

---

In your proof, the one ${\to}\mathsf I$ is discharging **both** ocurrances of the same assumption, $Q$.

$$\dfrac{\lower{2ex}{[Q]^1}\quad\dfrac{P\quad[Q]^1}{P\wedge Q}{{\wedge}\mathsf I}}{Q\to P\wedge Q}{{\to}\mathsf I^1}$$

There is nothing wrong with doing it that way; but it makes the proof bloated. The lower assumption is redundant, since it us not used for anything else.

So the proof can be pruned to just:

$$\dfrac{\dfrac{P\quad[Q]^1}{P\wedge Q}{{\wedge}\mathsf I}}{Q\to P\wedge Q}{{\to}\mathsf I^1}$$

Comment: Notice how bookkeeping where and when assumptions are discharged, makes the proof easier to check.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I have one more question though. Why is the lower assumption needed? From the definition of implication introduction that I have read, it looks like having a proof of P that assumes Q is all I need to deduce implication. So I am confused by the presence of this leftmost Q.

Comment: It is an assumption that has been reiterated into the sub-tree.  As mentioned, this is redundant.  You don't have to do it that way, but it is not wrong to highlight the assumption being discharged by placing it on the line of inference doing so

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you for the clarification

Answer (score 0):

There are various notations for deductive book-keeping; let us leave aside trying to guess the notation in the question and consider the underlying idea of assumption discharge: We assume a formula *for the sake of argument* and derive others. When the assumption has been discharged, the resultant formula has to be independent of the truth-value of the assumption. A shortcut example:

As a premiss, we have $\phi$. Then, we assume $\neg\phi$. We can write $$\phi\wedge\neg\phi$$

which is a contradiction that falsifies our assumption. Hence, we discharge the assumption $\neg\phi$ to get

$$\phi\vdash\neg\neg\phi$$

or,

$$\vdash\phi\rightarrow\neg\neg\phi.$$

Notice that the conclusion is independent of the truth-value of the assumption.

In the question, at the step of conjunction introduction, the assumption $Q$ is not discharged, for $P\wedge Q$ is dependent on both the premiss $P$ and the assumption $Q$. It is discharged with the introduction of material implication.

Comment: Perhaps the important point is that the conditional introduction is discharging **both** ocurrances of the same assumption.

Comment: @GrahamKemp That seems harmless, but against the idea. The assumption is essentially no different than saying in a discussion "suppose we're traveling in a blackhole . . ."; hence, so long as the argument goes, "we travel in a blackhole". Similarly, an assumption is reusable (that is, it can have multiple occurrences) within the allowed compartment (branch, box, etc. according to the system) until it is discharged. In other words, we discharge not the occurrences, but the assumption itself and once.

Comment: It is basically the Rule of Reiteration as implemented in this tree structure: an assumption discharged by an inference line may occur at the top of multiple branches above that line.  Rather than having a seperate indicator for reiteration, the discharge bookmarks are often reused.  (Well, that is if the bookmarking is used.)